# Why can't $( t, ±\sqrt{1-t^2})$ be the parametrization of a Circle?

Tags: geometry

See this image to understand my question:

[image: See this image to understand my question]

Comment: Just a tip, don't write $x^1(t)$ because that looks like $x'(t)$ which is the derivative of $x(t)$. If you write $x(t)$ it is understood to be $x^1(t)$

Comment: A curve is a function $f$ which takes each value $t$ from an interval, say $(0,1)$, to $\Bbb R^n$. If the sign $±$ is taken, we can't say that it is a curve. It takes a single parameter to different points in the Euclidean $n$-space.

Comment: I suggest you write $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ instead of $x^1(t)$ and $x^2(t)$.

Comment: Why don't you write your question, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#The_circle_example

Answer (score 3):

A parametrisation is a *function* whose image is the desiried object to be parametrized. $t \mapsto (t,\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}) t\in [0,1]$ is not a function - it's two functions, or a multivalued function.

$t \mapsto (t,+\sqrt{1-t^2}) t\in [0,1]$ is a perfect parametrization of the upper half of the circle, but only that.

Answer (score 3):

You parameterized the parabola as $y=x^2$, which is a univocal equation, and not as $x=\pm\sqrt y$. Think that $x$ can't be two values at a time.

For the same reason $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ doesn't work, and $x=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$ wouldn't be better.

For a continuous parameterization of a full circle, you could play with

$$\begin{cases}t\in[-1,1]\to(t,\sqrt{1-t^2}),\\t\in[1,3]\to(2-t,-\sqrt{1-(2-t)^2}).\end{cases}$$